# remove fixed number of digits

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

Maybe this is not so hard for you but I need some help. I have and editText that shows a code of 6 digits length. e.g. "292000", "123000", etc...

I have this info in an editText I would like that the user only can remove the last 2 digits to put their own number (they can only change the last two digits). e.g. "292020" "123001".

I'm using textwatchers but I can't use setText inside it because I'll get a stackoverflow error. Any help will be so appreciated.

```
codArt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(codArt.getSelectionStart() < 5) {
                codArt.setText(charSequence);
                codArt.setSelection(5);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove code from onTextChanged() method and try like below...

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (s.length() == 4 && after == 0) {
                codArt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                codArt.setText(s);
                codArt.setSelection(s.length());
                codArt.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much that solution fits perfect for me. I imagine that the call to removeTextChangedListener is to avoid the recursion in which I get the stackoverflow exception, isn't it?.

Comment: Yes..to avoid recursive call of listener methods I removed the listener before calling setText().

Answer (score 0):

Try using a textview with seteditable set as true. Set the min characters at "n" and keep the last "k" characters as editable. A custom textview would do the trick

Comment: Can I use ImeOptions and that kind of things with a textView?

Comment: Sorry but I tried this and it's not working. TextView does not have built-in support and I need these kind of functionalities

Comment: yeah i understand that Android's native textview does not support this. Did you try to write your own customTextView. You could impose these conditions there